# orientdb "not contains" fails with parsing exception

Tags: orientdb

I'm using orientdb version: 2.1.8

The following query fails with a parsing exception:

```
select from some_vertex where in('<edge_name>').id not contains "1"
```

Error:

`com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #0: Error parsing query: select from room where in('inroom').id not contains "1" Encountered "" at line 1, column 24`.

Was expecting one of:

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to exclude a determinate value you can use 'NOT IN' syntax. In your case the query would be like this:

```
select from Room where in('inRoom').id not in '1'
```

I tried the query with a structure `Furniture --inRoom-> Room` and it returns all of the Room vertex not connected with the Furniture.id `1`

Comment: Hi Avi Levi, did you have a chance to try the query ?